# How to call controller function in another controller in kohana

Tags: kohana

I just want to call my controller function in another controller using kohana. Here i am attached what i tried.

$file       = Reports_Controller::getpdf($reportname, $model);

Answer (score 2):

You should make internal Request.

```
<?php

class Controller_Report extends Controller {
    // report/get_pdf
    public function action_get_pdf()
    {
        echo 'echo PDF here!';
    }
}

class Controller_Page extends Controller {
    public function action_index()
    {
        $response = Request::factory('report/get_pdf')
            ->method('GET')
            ->query($data) // or ->post($data)
            ->execute();
        $response->status(); // 404 or 200 etc
        $response->headers();
        $response->body();
    }
}
```